# С99 и объявление переменной

Tags: c

Стандартом написано что переменные в блоке создаются при входе в него. Но как в С99, если в нем переменные можно объявлять не в начале блока? Все равно создаются при входе в блок?

Comment: если оптимизатор не принял решения размещать переменные в регистрах, то ему дешевле выделить место в стеке под все переменные за один раз. ибо скорость операции выделения места в стеке (по крайней мере на intel платформе и некоторых других) постоянна и не зависит от объема занимаемого переменными. с точки зрения программиста при этом ничего не изменится, он будет видеть свою переменную с момента ее объявления, но не раньше. И надо понимать, что "создание" переменной и ее инициализация это разные действия и оптимизатор может выполнять каждое из них тогда, когда считает нужным

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Понимаете, вопрос о том, когда именно они создаются - совершенно праздный.
Допустим, создаются в начале блока.
Или, допустим, не создаются в начале блока.
Или при одном ключе создаются, при другом - нет.

Вы-то все равно, пока не достигнете объявления переменной, никак не можете к ней обратиться. Очень многое зависит от оптимизатора - решит ли он размещать переменную в стеке или в регистре, разместит ли он ее в отдельной области памяти или в области, которая была занята другой переменной, но которая больше не используется.

Так что дать точный ответ на вопрос, как мене кажется, можно один - depends on :) Не уверен (если ошибаюсь - пусть гуру поправят), но такие вещи стандарт должен отдавать на откуп компилятору.